# generalization of an animated jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am noob in jquery. and i am trying to do the flowing :

i need that each menu collapse separately when mouse hover it .The problem that the 2 menu collapse simultaneously! 
I'm sure it's something basic, but I can't seem to figure it out.
please help. Thx

```js
            $(document).ready(function() {

              $(".lead-title-index").hover(function() {
                $(".featured-content").slideDown("slow");

              });

            });
```

```css
.featured-content {
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  display: none;
  background: #2E2E2E;
}
.lead-title-index {
  background: #FFBF00;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  position: relative;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-15 col-sm-3">

  <div class="lead-title-index">

  </div>

  <article id="video" class="featured-content">

    <div class="promo-text">

    </div>
  </article>
</div>

<div class="col-md-15 col-sm-3">

  <div class="lead-title-index">

  </div>

  <article id="video" class="featured-content">

    <div class="promo-text">

    </div>
  </article>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use next item after selected item like below,

```
        $(document).ready(function() {

          $(".lead-title-index").hover(function() {
            $(this).next(".featured-content").slideDown("slow");

          });

        });
```